# Accessing attribute from xml string in php

Tags: php, xml

I have a php application and I am trying to echo a atrribute from the xml.

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <header 
xmlns="xxx:xxx:xxxx:xxx:respUploadFisier:v1" dateResponse="202202" 
ExecutionStatus="0" index="206"/>
```

This is what I have tried till now:

```
xml = simplexml_load_string($result2);
foreach($xml->header[3]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
```

But it gives me this errors:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, 
 '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\efactura\verificastarea.php on line 80

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF- 
8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes in C:\xampp\htdocs\efactura\verificastarea.php on line 80

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\efactura\verificastarea.php on 
line 80

Notice: Trying to get property 'header' of non-object in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\fact\verificastarea.php on line 81

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\fact\verificastarea.php on line 81

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function attributes() on null in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\fact\verificastarea.php:81 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\fact\verificastarea.php on line 81
```

Can someone give me an example to extract from the xml from the beginning of the post the index ? Thanks in advance. I am a newbie in php

Comment: Looks like your XML is encoded so that `<` in the string is `$lt;`.  You need to decode it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a specific attribute you can try like this :

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($myXMLData) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

function xml_attribute($object, $attribute)
{
    if(isset($object[$attribute]))
        return (string) $object[$attribute];
}

print_r(xml_attribute($xml,'dateResponse'));
```

Comment: I get this errors: Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\efactura\verificastarea.php on line 83

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;yes in C:\xampp\htdocs\efactura\verificastarea.php on line 83

Warning: simplexml_load_string(): ^ in C:\xampp\htdocs\efactura\verificastarea.php on line 83
Error: Cannot create object

Comment: it seems your XML data is converted to HTML special characters , could you please try $myXMLData = htmlspecialchars_decode($myXMLData); before passing it to the function simplexml_load_string()

Comment: You're missing a value if the attribute is not set. Better use the `??` operator: `var_dump((string)($xml['dataResponse'] ?? ''));`. No need for the function.